# Update a date in PLSQL every year

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to get the date 01/12/(current year - 1)
In other words if it is 2016 I want the variable to be 01/12/15, if it's 2017 to be 01/12/16.. and so on 
Using PLSQL. Is there a way to do this? And if so thanks a lot for your help :D!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved through a sql query
`select add_months( sysdate, -12) from dual;`

or if your passing year this can be achieved through function.

```
create or replace
function  Yr (P_Year Date)

Return Date
As
Out_Year Date;
begin
Select Add_Months( P_Year, -12) Into Out_Year From Dual;
return out_year;
end;

select yr(sysdate) from dual;
output :-09-JUN-15
```

Answer (score 1):

```
trunc( sysdate, 'YYYY' )
```

will give you January 1 of the current year.

```
add_months( trunc( sysdate, 'YYYY' ), -12 )
```

will give you January 1 of the previous year

```
add_months( trunc( sysdate, 'YYYY' ), -12 ) + 11
```

will give you January 12 of the previous year

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope this helps.

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YEAR'),-1) FROM DUAL;


------------------------------OUTPUT--------------------------------------------

ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YEAR'),-1)
12/01/2015

------------------------------OUTPUT--------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following snippet mentioned below

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -12)
   FROM dual;
```